# django POST data not working

Tags: python, django, post

I want when I click the blue div in `/circle` page, send the value "niloofar" to `/final` and the output must be `** niloofar **`, but it doesnt work.

How I can edit it?
I want to send the value by hidden input.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def circle(request):
    return render(request, 'circle.html')


def final(request):
    matn = request.POST.get("title", "")
return render(request, 'final.html', {'matn': matn})
```

circle.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:lightblue;
} 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="/final">
    <div></div> 
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="niloofar">
</a>
```

final.html:

```
** {{ matn }} **
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from secondv.views import circle, final

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^circle/', circle),
    url(r'^final/', final),
]
```

Comment: Well where do you define `message`? *What* does "doesnt work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: there is no error just the value wont appear, only starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `POST` from a link. Change it to use a `form` instead:

```
<style>
.mysubmit {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:lightblue;
} 
</style>
```

and

```
<form action="/final" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="niloofar">
    <input type="submit" class="mysubmit" value="">
</form>
```

also change your view to:

```
def final(request):
    matn = request.POST.get("title", "")
    return render(request, 'final.html', {'matn': matn})
```

Comment: You definitely *can* POST from a link, though you'll need ajax: `<a href="#" onmousedown='$.ajax(config)'></a>`. Your answer may be the preferred and superior solution, but it is simply incorrect to say that you cannot POST from a link. You can POST from any HTML element whatsoever if you'd like, but whether or not it is a good idea is a completely different story... (Use a form in most situations like you said, it would be *stupid* to use a link but you *can* use a link.)

Comment: @YungGun Your example is not POSTing from a **link**. That is POSTing using an `<a>` tag. A link is not the same thing as any clickable piece of text. By this logic you can also POST from a `<blink>` tag. You can GET using a link but not POST.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `<a>` and this will issue a 'GET' request. 
To submit a `POST` you have to use a `

```
<form action='/final' method='post'>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="niloofar">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```